# Probably of winning with 2 dice against 1

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, conditional-probability

could some of you help me to find out what is the probability of A) obtain with two dice a greather number than another die?
B) and if the dice are 3 how can I do?
Not the sum of the 2 dice, but the greatest value of those 2 against another die

Comment: There are $\;6^3=216\;$ possible outcomes when you throws 3 dice. If you don't distinguish between the two dice and *the* one die, count in how many of these outcomes two results summed is great than the third outcome...

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is the sum of the two dice, and $Y$ the value of the one die, then
what are the possible outcomes $(x,y)$ and which one are "winning"? Then compute their probabilities by independence and add.

Or compute when the one die wins :

$P(Y=6)P(X \le 5) + P(Y=5)P(X \le 4) + P(Y=4)P(X \le 3) + P(Y=3)P(X \le 2)$

which equals $\frac{1}{6}(\frac{1}{36} + \frac{3}{36} + \frac{6}{36} + \frac{10}{36})$

and take the complement of that.

Comment: I'm not talking about the sum of the dice but about the maximum value of those two. For example, I roll 2 dice and obtain 5 and 2, roll another and I obtain 3. I want to compare 5 with 3, so the max of those 2 against the one

Comment: @NicholasSalis then adapt the computation.